# Embedding a scrolled down page in HTML

Tags: html, scroll, embed

I want to embed a page from around 200px down. Is it possible to make an embedded page (for example, an embedded Youtube page scrolled down to the comments)? This code worked for the embed itself - `<iframe src="(webpage)" width="800" height="452" frameborder="0">`. I'm *assuming* it's HTML. Please let me know if it is poorly phrased for the section.

Comment: Nope. An Youtube.com iframe will not work because of the same origin policy. See the youtube api instead ( and learn html,css,js)

Comment: Ah, okay. Would that apply to other websites? Youtube was just an example (the actual website already worked as an embed).

Comment: Website owners can disable the cross origin blocking for specific files, but basically it applies to every page that dont change it , except your own.

Comment: You cannot access the content of an iframe, but you could use url selectors ("http:// coolpage#comments") this only works if the part you want to focus has sth like name="comments" in its html

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot :)